# How to find iBeacon without beacon identifier?

Tags: ios, ibeacon, uuid

I am using the following line of code to create `CLBeaconRegion` and then called `location manager` in following way:

```
 let beaconRegion:CLBeaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: beaconUUID as UUID,
                                                                 identifier: beaconIdentifier)

///  save a beacon region for stopping after.
                (beaconInfo as! BeaconInfo).beaconRegion = beaconRegion

                ///  start monitoring the specified region.
                self.locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)

                ///  start calculating ranges for beacons in the specified region.
                self.locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
```

The code inside location Manager delegate is :

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                         didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon],
                         in region: CLBeaconRegion) {

        ///  it may be assumed no beacons that match the specified region are nearby.
        if beacons.count == 0 {
            print ("beacon.count = 0")
            return
        }
else
{
     \\executed rest of the code
}
```

where beaconUUID is the UUID of my iBeacon and beaconIdentifier is the identifier string. The issue is that as my app will detect generic iBeacons, so I might not be aware of their beaconIdentifier string (which is not the UUID, just an identifier). Is there any way in which I can pass this as a generic string or nil (to remove the dependancy)?

Edit: Added CLLocationManager code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was that each beacon needs to have unique identifier string. That is why my app was not detecting because I had a common string for all beacons.

Answer (score 6):

No, you need to know the UUID of the beacons that you are looking for.  There is no way with iOS to scan for "all beacons".

The identifier string is just a string you are assigning to the `CLBeaconRegion` in your app.  It has no relation to any value configured in the actual beacon.

So

```
let beaconRegion:CLBeaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: beaconUUID as UUID, identifier: "someIdentifier")
```

and

```
let beaconRegion:CLBeaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: beaconUUID as UUID, identifier: "someOtherIdentifier")
```

will both scan for the same set of iBeacons; iBeacons with the UUID specified by `beaconUUID`

You can use the identifier to identify a beacon region at a later time, such as when the region is entered or you want to stop monitoring a region.  Remember that beacon regions remain active across executions of your app, so you cannot rely on an object reference.

Comment: I am talking about the beacon identifier, not the beacon UUID. I'll edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: The beacon identifier is just a string you assign when you create the CLBeaconRegion; It has no relation to the beacon itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, @Paulw11 is correct.  There is no public API on iOS to find all beacons regardless of ProximityUUID.

Comment: Paul gave you the answer. The only things that define a beacon are the UUID, major, and minor IDs. The identifier is a name for you. The OS gives that back to you when it detects a beacon that matches your UUID, UUID + major ID, or UUID + Major ID + Minor ID. Think of it as a beacon name, e.g. "Fred". You say "Location manager, look for a beacon with UUID xyz. We'll call it Fred." The location manager then says "I detected Fred!" The beacon doesn't know or care that you and iOS have decided to name it Fred.

Comment: @DuncanC In my case, delegate method for location manager - didRangeBeacons isn't detecting the CLBeaconRegion if I give "someOtherIdentifier" instead of "someIdentifier" and that's a concern.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You should look for some other cause for failing to detect the beacon. The identifier is purely for your use.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your didRangeBeacons method?

Comment: @DuncanC can you check now please, I have edited it.